# Unable to load a ListPreference Dialog in a PreferenceScreen held by an ActivityGroup

Tags: android, listpreference

I have an `ActivityGroup` implemented on a certain tab. One of the screens in this `ActivityGroup` is a `PreferenceScreen` and consists of a `ListPreference` in it.

On clicking the `ListPreference` an exception is thrown and it fails to load the dialog. Here is the full stack trace of the exception:-

```
05-08 12:05:31.545: E/AndroidRuntime(247): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token    android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44ec8ac8 is not valid; is your activity running?
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:468)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.preference.DialogPreference.showDialog(DialogPreference.java:307)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.preference.DialogPreference.onClick(DialogPreference.java:265)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:811)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:190)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-08 12:05:31.585: E/AndroidRuntime(247):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I also tried implementing a DialogPreference instead of a ListPreference but it still crashes in the same way.

It worked well before adding the `Activity` to an `ActivityGroup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this problem by setting the parent's context to the listpreference.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply. It was an easy fix actually. Just create your List dynamically and not by static xml file. Set your list's context to that of parent and you are done

Comment: Thanks Vaidehi! Well, it was a a TabHost issue. It made me to force the context with preferences.